# How to pass image to other activity with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-camera

I have a bottom bar. And It has a camera icon. When I click the icon. It shows me a dialog. This dialog has 3 buttons. These are camera request, gallery request and cancel. I take a photo with camera request to doing that I used to intent. And I press commit button ( in emulator default button). But It gives me an exception. My purpose is: I want to send that taken photo to other activity. Then set it to my image view. How can I do that?

Here is my commit button : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP18K.png)

[image]

my Logcat :

```
05-20 15:25:01.635 2653-2653/something.about.berkay.isim E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: something.about.berkay.isim, PID: 2653
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {something.about.berkay.isim/something.about.berkay.isim.bottom_bar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at something.about.berkay.isim.bottom_bar.onActivityResult(bottom_bar.java:186)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code :

```
  private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
   private void openCamera() {

        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePicture, CAMERA_REQUEST);


        try {
           /* camera.takePicture();*/
            dialog.dismiss();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


       switch (requestCode){
           case GALLERY_REQUEST : if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){   //gallery için 1
               Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            //   deneme.setImageURI(selectedImage);
           }break;
           case CAMERA_REQUEST : if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

              Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           Intent i = new Intent(bottom_bar.this , fotograf_cekildikten_sonra_kaydet_iptal_yeri.class);
           i.putExtra("dene " ,selectedImage);
         startActivity(i);



           }

       }
```

Other my activity :

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fotograf_cekildikten_sonra_kaydet_iptal_yeri);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Uri uri = extras.getParcelableExtra("dene");
    ımageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.telefon_arama_ImageView);

    ımageView.setImageResource(uri);
```

Comment: what exception ?

Comment: I editted my question. now

Comment: The problem is in `fotograf_cekildikten_sonra_kaydet_iptal_yeri.onCreate`, which is not the code you posted, if I'm right.

Comment: _"And I press commit button ( in emoletor default button). But It gives me exception._"  Where is commit button code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: just send the file path of the image as string and load the image from that path in the next activity.

Answer (score 2):

Intents are not intended to be used for passing big data. It is a messaging mechanism within your process(application) or IPC. If you try to pass a big data
you will probably get a TransactionTooLargeException. What you can do is you can save the photo to your local file system and then pass the uri of that photo to
other activity through Intent. Here is the official guide for how to do that:
[photobasics](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)